# YAML - Dynamic Values substitution

Tags: yaml

I am trying to configure a yml where I need to do something like below

```
---
en :[dev, uat]
application.url: https://domainname-appname-${en}.com:8080/someendpoint/
---

en : prod
application.url: https://domainname-appname.com/CONTEXT/someendpoint/
```

I am passing en param as a placeholder by using value of en param in url
I also need to pass port as a param something like for each value of en

```
en :[dev, uat]
application.url: https://domainname-appname-${en}.com:${port}/someendpoint/
```

for dev port should be 8080
for uat port should be 9090

Is there any way in YML we can represent this, for each value of en need to map a port like Map key value pair ?

Answer (score 1):

YAML is not a data processor. It cannot replace anything, it cannot concatenate anything, it cannot map anything.

That being said, most tools that read in complex YAML configuration which might require parameterization do provide you with some form of templating, which you can use to configure the YAML file before it is parsed. However, this is specific for each tool so there will not be a general solution.